# INNER JOIN returning un-expected NULL (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop, inner-join

I am currently running a function which uses an inner join in a while loop which is un-expectedly returning nothing back.

```
$data3 = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $posted_email) . '\'';

$exam_recordation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE Student_email = $data3) AND Student_email <> $data3");
//$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT student.email, student.name, Student_email FROM student INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email WHERE student.email = $data3")

echo "<table border=='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Exam Date</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Mark</th>
    <th>Style</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email <>{$data3}");
//die();
 /*while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($name_query))
  {
    echo "<td>" . $row1['name'] . "</td>"; //This while loop was just me overcomplicating it, soon worked out I didnt need it
  }*/
  echo "<td>" . $name_query['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['examDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mark'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['style'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

From my own attempt to debug it I have realised that it is returning not the value I wish (the name out of the student table) but a NULL value when I run it in a seperate PHP function on its own i.e. not inside a while loop shown below.

```
$data3 = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $posted_email) . '\'';
var_dump($posted_email);
var_export($data3);
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email <> $data3");
var_export($name_query);
echo "SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email <> $data3";
```

However, when I run the echo'd INNER JOIN from that last bit of code in SQL it works fine and returns 2 rows of names.

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.name FROM student INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email WHERE student.email <> 'eating@gnomes.com'
```

The theory I'm working towards is something along the lines of:

```
$name_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student.name
              FROM student
              INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
              WHERE student.email <>{$data3}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation) && mysql_fetch_array($name_query))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['examDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mark'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['style'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

That returns nothing to my table but what I'm trying to do is use both queries in one fetch so as to put the results of them both into $row and be able to extract the relevant data. That actually sounds quite far fetched, so if it is take it as inexperience on my part to fault.

As I hope you can see, I have tried to figure out what the problem is but have failed. Usually just checking that the query being sent is correct has fixed this kind of problem of nothing being returned for me in the past but not so it seems for this problem. May be it is something I am missing with the array or while loop, may be not. I have run out of ideas really.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have some exam results for this student?

INNER JOIN will only return results when data exists in both joined tables.

Try using LEFT JOIN to see if that returns.

Also test your queries in something like phpMyAdmin or the MySQL console to decide if it's the query at fault of you processing of the results.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. I have used the SQL console as such in myphpadmin to test the query that came out of the echo of the INNER JOIN query and it returned 2 rows. I'm guessing that is what you mean.

Comment: phpmyadmin that is, not myphpadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You commented the fetch method, it won't work with out it.
This is the way you should take the name:

```
$rowStudent = mysql_fetch_array($name_query);
echo "<td>" . $rowStudent['name'] . "</td>";
```

mysql_query only sends and excecute the query, to get results you need the fetch.

Also you can check if you got results with `if($rowStudent)` or `if(!$rowStudent)` to handle no results.

Comment: Right, first thanks for taking the time to help. I tried your solution by using your code to replace: `echo "<td>" . $name_query['name'] . "</td>";` It brings up the name but it uses the first name to cover all results. For example by the end of that function, I have two rows of which both have the name of the first record but should only be on the first of the two records i.e. result 1 has name bob, result 2 has name bob when it should be mary as an example of what is happening. Would putting your bit of code inside the while loop I commented out sort that out?

Comment: Just tried adding your bit of code to inside my commented out while loop and all it has done is it is now using the second result's name for both results so the name for result 1 is now mary when it should be bob and result 2 name is mary correctly keeping to above example.

Comment: But you are always looking for student.email <>{$data3} , as $data3 doesn't change you'll get always the same result. Or can you have more than one email or email-student combination?. You also should be able to write all in one query, I'll edit the answer with the query.

Comment: remember each time mysql_fetch_array gets called it advances the results, you might be keeping the last result in the $rowStudent with with that loop skipping to the end.

Comment: One student will only ever have one email connected to them to clear that up. EDIT: right, hence why with it inside my commented out while loop it replaced the name with the second name as the second fetch would have advanced its selection by one.

Comment: and one email will have only one student? or more? Why did you commented out the second query with the join? I think that's the way to go.

Comment: its a one to one relationship. student will/can only have one email and one email will only ever be associated to one student. EDIT:At the time I thought I needed to have the join in the while loop given I needed a variable that was only available from within it. But then I was using the wrong variable, totally forgot about that first commented out join at the top. No idea how and I now do see it as being the more sensible option.

Comment: But if I were to use the top commented join instead, how would I access it like I have $exam_recordation without adding another while loop in the current loop or mysql_fetch onto the end of the current one if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, it has only one query which joins the two tables.

```
$data3 = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $posted_email) . '\'';

$exam_recordation = mysql_query("SELECT student.name, exam.Student_email,
            exam.examDate, exam.level, exam.mark, exam.style 
            FROM student INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email 
            WHERE student.email <> $data3");

echo "<table border=='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Exam Date</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Mark</th>
    <th>Style</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exam_recordation))
  {
  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Student_email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['examDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mark'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['style'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: exam recordation finds, according to the inserted email, any one else in the exam table with the same partner_id as them in any exam row they have been found on. So, eating@gnomes.com has two entries in the exam table with partner_id's 1 and 2, all other partners with those id's are selected.The INNER JOIN intended use was to get the partner's the exam recordation found name from the student table from their email found in the exam table. Your query looks to have mixed things up abit, as it returns everyone except the person with the linked email used to perform the query i.e. as data3.

Comment: Will try and see if I can do the query in the way I wish it but the help would be appreciated if you have any suggestions on how it should be.

Comment: `SELECT student.name, exam.Student_email,
      exam.examDate, exam.level, exam.mark, exam.style, exam.partner_id 
      FROM student INNER JOIN exam ON student.email = exam.Student_email
      WHERE student.email <> 'prof@nuts.com' AND exam.partner_id = 1` is more like what I'm looking with the big if being if it is possible to make that last WHERE condition have multiple values as at the moment it returns the correct result for an email who is a part of of only one pair. What about an email who is apart of more than one pair in that table?

Comment: Except the above code does look to include the exam results of the used email i.e. prof@nuts.com which the <> was suppose to avoid.